# Как создать файловый поток в Xamarin(C#)?

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, xamarin, mobile-development

Нужно открыть поток для чтения бинарного файла, но выдаёт ошибку.Я делал десктопное приложение, а нужно на мобильное. Подскажите пожалуйста, я новичок в этом деле.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using System.IO;

namespace Test_PD
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        double[] normal = new double[3];
        double[] vertex1 = new double[3];
        double[] vertex2 = new double[3];
        double[] vertex3 = new double[3];
        ushort count;
        double sum = 0;
        byte[] header = new byte[80];

            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open("file.stl", FileMode.Open)))
            {
                FileStream file1 = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Create);[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file1);
                reader.BaseStream.Seek(84,SeekOrigin.Begin);
                while(reader.BaseStream.Position != reader.BaseStream.Length)
                {
                        for (int i = 0; i< 3; i++) normal[i] = reader.ReadSingle();
                        for (int i = 0; i< 3; i++) vertex1[i] = reader.ReadSingle();
                        for (int i = 0; i< 3; i++) vertex2[i] = reader.ReadSingle();
                        for (int i = 0; i< 3; i++) vertex3[i] = reader.ReadSingle();
                        count = reader.ReadUInt16();
                        sum = sum + ((((-1) * vertex3[0] * vertex2[1] * vertex1[2]) + vertex2[0] * vertex3[1] * vertex1[2] + vertex3[0] * vertex1[1] * vertex2[2] - vertex1[0] * vertex3[1] * vertex2[2] - vertex2[0] * vertex1[1] * vertex3[2] + vertex1[0] * vertex2[1] * vertex3[2]) / 6);
                        writer.WriteLine("  facet normal " + normal[0] + " " + normal[1] + " " + normal[2]);
                        writer.WriteLine("    outer loop");
                        writer.WriteLine("      vertex " + vertex1[0] + " " + vertex1[1] + " " + vertex1[2]);
                        writer.WriteLine("      vertex " + vertex2[0] + " " + vertex2[1] + " " + vertex2[2]);
                        writer.WriteLine("      vertex " + vertex3[0] + " " + vertex3[1] + " " + vertex3[2]);
                        writer.WriteLine("    endloop");
                        writer.WriteLine("  endfacet");
                }
                sum = sum / 1000;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: а как он узнает где лежит файл, если вы задали только имя? И тут хоть бы саму ошибку показали.

Comment: и FileStream с StreamWriter не забудтье закрыть